# Inheriting T from from Collection<T>

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I came across the following usage of Inheriting from a Generic Collection.

```
class Model : Collection<Model>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

And it can be instantiated as :

```
 var model = new Model {Name = "Name1", Password = "Pass1"};
 model.Add(new Model { Name = "Name2", Password = "Pass2" });
 model.Add(new Model { Name = "Name3", Password = "Pass3" });
```

And I can access `model` both as single instance as well as a collection object.

```
 Console.Out.WriteLine("Original:  " + model.Name + " : " + model.Password + Environment.NewLine);

 foreach (var m in model)
 {
    Console.Out.WriteLine(m.Name + " : " + m.Password + Environment.NewLine);
 }
```

How is this possible, and what is really happening under the covers ?

Edit: To further clarify, `model` has a single instance which is separate, where I can access `model.Name` (*Name1*) and not a part of the collection, where I can access `model[0].Name` (*Name2*). This dual nature is what confuses me.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be possible? It's pretty much just doing Collection<Collection<Model>> with some extra bells and whistles.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. The last block of code (where you're referring to a `single instance as well as a collection object` is simply iterating each item in the collection via a `foreach` loop; in other words, it's iterating through the collection `model`, assigning each item in the collection to the variable `m`, and accessing that variable `m`. There's no "both" here, and there's nothing happening "under the covers" in any of your posted code. (I didn't downvote - your qeustion is just unclear, and I'm asking you to [edit] to clarify what it is you're asking us.)

Comment: Nothing strange about the code except it being potentially confusing.

Comment: It's model capable of holding collection of models. Personally I'd have called it ModelCollection or some such

Comment: @KenWhite I added the line of code where I can access the properties that I set while instantiating the `model` object.

Comment: @AmitOlkar - You could maybe try yo be more explicit about what you don't understand. Right now you're collecting close votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About

```
 class Model : Collection<Model>
```

at first I would like to note that this does not look like a very good idea.

But it is not as confusing as it looks. There is no circular inheritance, just a forward reference to the `Model` type.

A slightly more sane version:

```
class Model
{
    public List<Model> SubModels { get; set; }
}
```

Here the `List<>` also contains a type that is not yet fully defined.

Comment: Presumably there would be other properties in `Model` besides `SubModels`.  Otherwise, it's just turtles all the way down.